# Looping through a nested object and imputed missed keys

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested

I'm new to javascript and trying to loop through a nested object to insert a missing key at the second level where I would like to add any missing keys below 5 and assign them a value of zero. So if we have keys 5 and 3, I would like to add 4, 2, and 1 keys with a value of zero.

'''0:{"key": "2010", "values": [
{ "key": "4",
"value": 10
},
{ "key": "3",
"value": 2
}
]}

1:{"key": "2011", "values": [
{ "key": "5",
"value": 25
},
{ "key": "3",
"value": 4
}
]}'''

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: This is just a copy and paste of [the question you asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73971646/looping-through-a-nested-object-and-imputed-missed-keys). It was closed **for a reason**. Don't just repost closed questions.

Comment: [As I said last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73971646/looping-through-a-nested-object-and-imputed-missed-keys#comment130609902_73971646), your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Also, the data structure shown doesn't make sense. Presumably there's some container around it. It's important to show us that.

Comment: Thank you T.J., I searched all over but could not figure it, I will keep on doing just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map over the existing data and check to see if the key exists already, hope this helps you understand what's happening.

```js
let data = [
  {
    key: "2010",
    values: [
      { key: "4", value: 10 },
      { key: "3", value: 2 },
    ],
  },
  {
    key: "2011",
    values: [
      { key: "5", value: 25 },
      { key: "3", value: 4 },
    ],
  },
];

data = data.map((currentItem) => {
    
  // Create a new temp values array
  const newValues = [];

  // Ensure all keys are present (between 1 and 5)
  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

    // Check to see if the key already exists
    const existingValue = currentItem.values.find(({ key }) => key === String(i));

    // Insert the existing value or initialise the key to 0
    newValues.push({ key: String(i), value: existingValue ? existingValue.value : 0 });
  }

  // Return the new object, replacing the values array with the new one
  return { ...currentItem, values: newValues };
});
```